# Dangling Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

I wrote a program in C having dangling pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *func(void)
{
    int num;
    num = 100;
    return &num;
}

int func1(void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    scanf("%d %d",&y,&z);
    x=y+z;
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a = func();
    int b;
    b = func1();
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the **output as 100** even though the pointer is dangling.

I made a single change in the above function `func1()`. Instead of taking the value of `y` and `z` from standard input as in above program, now I am assigning the value during compile time.

I redefined the `func1()` as follows:

```
int func1(void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    y=100;
    z=100;
    x=y+z;
    return x;
}
```

Now the **output is 200**.

Can somebody please explain me the reason for the above two outputs?

Comment: There's a code button you can use to make an entire section code, instead of using code snippets for each line.

Comment: For the first version, what inputs yield a result of 100?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Undefined Behavior** means anything can happen, including it'll do as you expect. Your stack variables weren't overwritten in this case.

```
void func3() {
  int a=0, b=1, c=2;
}
```

If you include a call to `func3()` in between `func1` and `printf` you'll get a different result.

EDIT: What actually happens on *some* platforms.

```
int *func(void)
{  
    int num;  
    num = 100;  
    return &num;  
}
```

Let's assume, for simplicity, that the stack pointer is 10 before you call this function, and that the stack grows upwards.

When you call the function, the return address is pushed on stack (at position 10) and the stack pointer is incremented to 14 (yes, very simplified). The variable num is then created on stack at position 14, and the stack pointer is incremented to 18.

When you return, you return a pointer to address 14 - return address is popped from stack and the stack pointer is back to 10.

```
void func2() {
    int y = 1;
}
```

Here, the same thing happens. Return address pushed at position, y created at position 14, you assign 1 to y (writes to address 14), you return and stack pointer's back to position 10.

Now, your old `int *` returned from `func` points to address 14, and the last modification made to that address was func2's local variable assignment. So, you have a dangling pointer (nothing above position 10 in stack is valid) that points to a left-over value from the call to `func2`

Comment: When I am using scanf(), why the answer is value of num. Whether the stack variable num is not overwritten by y or z. Can you explain me which variables go to stack?

Comment: The compiler is free to check out your app and figure "you need X bytes of stack total for these calls", set aside all of it in one go, and therefore you can get distinct addresses for local variables in these function calls. It's **undefined behavior** - You'll need to disassemble the executable to see exactly what's happening

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik for your detail explanation.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the way the memory gets allocated.

After calling `func` and returning a dangling pointer, the part of the stack where `num` was stored still has the value `100` (which is what you are seeing afterwards). We can reach that conclusion based on the observed behavior.

After the change, it looks like what happens is that the `func1` call overwrites the memory location that `a` points to with the result of the addition inside `func1` (the stack space previously used for `func` is reused now by `func1`), so that's why you see 200.

Of course, **all of this is undefined behavior** so while this might be a good philosophical question, answering it doesn't really buy you anything.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior. It could work correctly on your computer right now, 20 minutes from now, might crash in an hour, etc. Once another object takes the same place on the stack as `num`, you will be **doomed**!

Answer (score 1):

Dangling pointers (pointers to locations that have been disassociated) induce **undefined behavior**, i.e. anything can happen.

In particular, the memory locations get reused *by *chance*** in `func1`. The result depends on the stack layout, compiler optimization, architecture, calling conventions and stack security mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

With dangling pointers, the result of a program is undefined. It depends on how the stack and the registers are used. With different compilers, different compiler versions and different optimization settings, you'll get a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a pointer to a local variable yields undefined behaviour, which means that anything the program does (anything at all) is valid. If you are getting the expected result, that's just dumb luck.

Answer (score -1):

Please study functions from basic C. Your concept is flawed...`main` should be

```
int main(void)  
{  
    int *a = func();  
    int b;

    b = func1();  
    printf("%d\n%d",*a,func1());  
    return 0;  
}
```

This will output `100 200`