# static variable scope inside and outside the function

Tags: c

Please notice the static variable `selection`.
I am testing if the selection is assigned the correct char string within the different scope.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char* selection;

static char* sel_item(char* text)
{
    char* pch;
    char buf[80];
    strcpy(buf, text);
    pch = strtok(buf, " ");
    return pch;
}

static int display_ecnt_codes(char* text)
{   
    char buf[80];
    strcpy(buf, text); 
    selection = sel_item(buf);
    // why if I output the selection here, the selection is random char, not the correct char "SRFPRO".
    // printf("display_ecnt_codes: %s\n", selection); 
}

int acode_prockey()
{
    char text[] = "SRFPRO - Surface Protection (DealerProduct)";
    display_ecnt_codes(text); 
    // why if I output the selection here, it prints the correct char string "SRFPRO".
    // what's the difference between this scope and the above scope?
    printf("acode_prockey: %s\n", selection); 
}

int main ()
{
    acode_prockey();
    // it will output SRFPRO, the first token of the char text[].
    printf("main: %s\n", selection);  
}
```

I am hoping someone can explain the global static varible "selection".
When I printf it inside the function "display_ecnt_codes", it outputs the random char. If I do not printf it inside the function, it output the correct char in the main function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dangling Pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289015/dangling-pointer-in-c)

Comment: After sel_item returns, buf no longer exists (as buf is a local variable stored on the stack). Thus pch (which points to somewhere inside buf) is invalid and you are invoking undefined behavior (anything can happen, your program can crash, etc). You need to allocate the buf in sel_item using malloc (and don't forget to free!). I would recommend learning more about how memory allocation and lifetime works in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following function, you are returning a pointer that is not valid after the function returns.

```
static char* sel_item(char* text)
{
    char* pch;

    // An array on the stack
    char buf[80];
    strcpy(buf, text);

    // A pointer to some element of the array.
    pch = strtok(buf, " ");

    // Returns a pointer that is not valid after the function returns.
    return pch;
}
```

Later on, you use that invalid pointer which is stored in `selection`. Your program exhibits undefined behavior because of that.