# Why value of 'x' is printed in main, when it might have been deallocated while coming out of abc()?

Tags: c, pointers

In the mentioned code, after the pointer is assigned to x in function abc(), it prints the value of x in abc(), after coming out of abc() the pointer should not be pointing to x anymore as 'x' might have been deallocated and it should result in a dangling pointer, but this is not the case, it prints the value of 'x' in main as well, How?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void abc();
int* ptr = NULL;
void abc()
{ 
    int x = 10; 
    ptr = &x; 
    printf("in abc ptr: %d",*ptr);
    printf("\n");
} 
int main()
{
    abc();
    printf("in main ptr: %d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dangling Pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289015/dangling-pointer-in-c)

Comment: [Undefined behavior is undefined](https://www.google.com/search?q="undefined+behavior+is+undefined"+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Call a function after `abc()` returns and before `printf()` in `main()`.  That function could be `void setx(int y) { int x = y; printf("y = %d\n", y); }` and the call `setx(-398812);`.  Then see what you get.  But UB is UB — any result is OK.

Comment: Your question is logically equivalent to, "I was driving along last night, and I came to a red light.  I decided to drive through the intersection anyway.  No other cars hit me, and no policeman gave me a ticket.  Why not?"

Answer (score 3):

Just because you aren't allowed to do something doesn't mean it won't work. C doesn't make sure that everything you do is valid. The pointer doesn't point to a valid variable, but it does point to memory that could happen to still have the correct pattern to be an an `int` 10.

Calling other functions, particularly one that uses local variables, between the call to `abc` and the `printf` line could result in that value being overwritten.

As it is now, this code causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: To add to this answer, using a library such as Visual Leak Detector or something else may help you to identify poor memory handling in your code. More here: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/memory-leak-detection-tools/

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't make that kind of checks, you are almost entirely responsible for the memory management of your program. The fact that the value in that memory address is still unaffected despite the fact that the stack frame of abc() doesn't exist anymore is just a result of "luck". To be more precise, that effect happens because C doesn't have a garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

What is printed is the object at the address where `x` *existed*.

If nothing reuses that memory the value will not generally change.  It *is* undefined behaviour, but for the most part when not required to do anything a C compiler does exactly nothing, and in this case that includes not explicitly modifying the memory previously used for `x` just because `x` is no longer in scope.

If a function with local variables that are modified were called between `abc()` and the print, the value would most likely be modified.

Answer (score 0):

As inspired by a comment by @JonathanLeffler, try changing your `main` function to

```
int main()
{
    abc();
    printf("in main: ");
    printf("ptr: %d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Rightly pointed out, using this code snippet the value printed on my console is '1967901216' (in main), but I am unable to justify this behavior.

Comment: @Anurag I thought your question was, "I expected this code to fail, but it worked."  Now the code is failing, as you expected. So what are you trying to justify?

Comment: yes the code fails, but the whole point is, when the control is out of 'abc()' it should fail instantly, so how could we justify the 'printf("in main: ")' statement?

Comment: But you see, there's no mechanism that would cause it to fail as it leaves `abc()`.  It's returning a pointer value, and the pointer value is in the process of becoming invalid, in that the location it points to is no longer guaranteed to contain the value 10.  But, the vast majority of the time, *invalid pointer values do NOT cause problems right away.*  Problems only start happening when you try to look at what the invalid pointer points to, by writing things like `printf("%d",*ptr)`

Comment: Think about it this way.  You write a letter.  You put it in an envelope, and on the outside you write the address "Steve Ssfdjkfsdj, 12345 Pearl St., Cambridge, MA, 02139, USA".  That's not a valid address.  (As it happens I do live on Pearl St. in Cambridge, but the house numbers only go up to about 250.) But nothing is going to go wrong when you mail this letter.  You can put it in a mailbox just fne, and your local post office can send it on its way to Cambridge just fine.  Nothing's going to go wrong until the envelope reaches the post office in Cambridge, MA, where they know it's bad.

Comment: @Anurag Please read all the other comments and answers.  They're all trying to explain how, why, and when the space allocated for variable `x` might go away or get reused.  (But no one can explain *exactly* how, why, or when, of course, because the results are undefined, so nothing's guaranteed.)

Comment: Ok so i guess since there is no explanation for how, why or when, and mostly the behavior is undefined, it's the characteristics of C itself, and we should try to deallocate pointers manually to ensure correct functioning.